# Ansible 2.9 Cisco IOS module loops

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to loop through the ios_l2_interfaces module and I am running into an issue where I cannot seem to get Ansible to loop through the module using my defined dictionaries.

I currently separate plays by the dictionaries' access/trunk value, and loop through items. But, this is also a challenge in the l3_interfaces and lag_interfaces modules. So I would like to solve this for these as well.

Say I have:

```
vars: 
interfaces:
  - name: test1/0/1
    access:
      vlan: 10
  - name: test2/0/1
    trunk
      allowed_vlans: 10,20,30
```

and

```
- name: Configure Trunk and Access Ports
  ios_l2_interfaces
    config:
      {{ item }}
    state: replaced
  with_items: {{ interfaces }}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
argument config is of type <type 'dict'> and we were unable to convert to list: <type 'dict'> cannot be converted to a list"
```

How do I write this play so that I can loop through dictionaries that have different attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out while I was writing this up... I was missing a '-' before my {{item}} declaration.

This worked:

```
- name: Configure Trunk and Access Ports
  ios_l2_interfaces
    config:
      - {{ item }}
    state: replaced
  with_items: {{ interfaces }}
```